# How to implement the concept of Reversible Routes in SailsJs

Tags: node.js, routes, sails.js

So I'm coming from Django where we enjoy a mature framework with many sensible conventions.

One of the biggest frustrations about any nodejs framework I've explored so far is the apparent disregard for reversible routes.

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1133

What I'd like to achieve is one of two things:

- get sailsjs to either implement a sensible routing library like one of those outlined in the issue ticket
- or what's more likely to occur, is fork sailjs and make it use one of those routing libraries in order to provide sane url tools in my controllers and views.

I think the person who made [Reverse](https://npmjs.org/package/reverse) sums it up:

```
Tired of hard-coding endpoints in your client-side JS? 
Exhausted from rewriting all of your redirects whenever you change your 
express routes?
```

Help me understand how I can make this happen. would it involve massive changes in sailsjs?

Comment: Actually, compoundJs seems to have some sanity about dealing with routes. http://compoundjs.com/man/routing.3.html#URL-HELPERS